# there are 'X' participants. The participants are to be divided into groups. Each group can have a minimum of 6 and a maximum of 10 participants

Tags: javascript

there are 'X' participants. The participants are to be divided into groups. Each group can have a minimum of 6 and a maximum of 10 participants. How would you approach this problem, and can you write code for this problem? Optimize for a minimum number of groups. Example: If there are 81 participants, then your program should split them into 9 groups, with each group having 9 participants.

Comment: Please edit the question and add in the relevant code segment, and then explain at what point in your code you're not getting the results you expect.

Comment: Do you have anything created already? if so please paste your code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with 90 participants and want to create new arrays with a max you could do something like this:

```js
let participants = []

for (let i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    participants.push("Participant" + i)
}

function splitArray(array, newArrayMaxLength) {
    var chunks = [], i = 0, n = array.length;
    while (i < n) {
        chunks.push(array.slice(i, i += newArrayMaxLength));
    }
    return chunks;
}

console.log(splitArray(participants, 9));
```

When you call this function, you pass with it an argument stating the max length of the new arrays. If the numbers does not add up, there will only be a difference with one, so ideally you would not have to do anything else, if you span is between 6-10.

Please in the future include your code if you have done any :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the classical coin change problem with result as sequence instead of minimum coins required. The base solution is recursive and given below.

```
function minGroup(groupSize, totalParticipants) {
// Base case
  if (totalParticipants == 0) return [];

  // Initialize result
    let groupArray = -1;

  // Try every group that is smaller
  // than totalParticipants
  for (let i = 0; i < groupSize.length; i++) {
      if (groupSize[i] <= totalParticipants) {
        let sub_arr = minGroup(groupSize, totalParticipants - groupSize[i]);

        // enters if new minGroup less than current or no current solution
        if (sub_arr !== -1 && (sub_arr.length + 1 < groupArray.length || groupArray === -1)) {
          groupArray = sub_arr.concat([groupSize[i]])
        }
    }
  }
    return groupArray
}
```

The solution can be improved on by Dynamic Programming with tabulation.

```
function minGroupDp(groupSize, totalParticipants) {


let dpTable = new Array(totalParticipants + 1);

  // base case
  dpTable[0] = [];

  // Initialize all dpTable values as -1
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalParticipants; i++) {
    dpTable[i] = -1;
  }

  // Compute minimum groupSize required for all
  // totalParticipantss from 1 to V

  for (let i = 1; i <= totalParticipants; i++) {
    // Go through all groupSize smaller than current total participants
    for (let j = 0; j < groupSize.length; j++)
      if (groupSize[j] <= i) {
        let sub_arr = dpTable[i - groupSize[j]];

        // enters if new minGroup less than current or no current solution
        if (
          sub_arr !== -1 &&
          (sub_arr.length + 1 < dpTable[i].length || dpTable[i] === -1)
        )
          dpTable[i] = sub_arr.concat([groupSize[j]]);
      }
  }

  return dpTable[totalParticipants];
}
```